# Swift how to get frame.width without setting frame?

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this textfield

```
let usn_text_field: LeftPaddedTextField = {
        let tf = LeftPaddedTextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Username"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tf
    }()
    usn_text_field.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: info_centill.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    usn_text_field.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor,constant:20).isActive = true
    usn_text_field.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor,constant:-75).isActive = true
```

And i wanted to add border layer to this tf and her is my code

```
let borderLayer = CALayer()
    borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x:-5,y:39,width:usn_text_field.frame.width,height:1)
    borderLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.6).cgColor
    usn_text_field.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

But this returns `usn_text_field.frame.width` as 0.How can i get `frame.width` without setting width or is there any other way to get the width of an element?

Comment: should it be 0?!

Comment: @AhmadF not it's actually over 300

Comment: Well maybe you should use `usn_text_field.frame.size.width` . I use this and it works for me.

Comment: use this to add border `usn_text_field.layer.borderWidth = 2` and `usn_text_field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor.cgColor`

Comment: @AlfredoLucoG i changed it,it still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `layoutIfNeeded` worked for me